# Posting photo in Facebook iOS SDK without loading the image file into app (just like video uploading)

Tags: ios, memory-management, facebook-ios-sdk, didreceivememorywarning, photo-upload

I have a memory-intensive photo app where loading a high resolution photo may crash my app due to memory consumption. I've managed to optimize my app, but my app still sometimes crashes due to memory warnings when loading large images (or creating a new image while a large photo is loaded etc). I need to post an image file in my app's documents directory directly, just like uploading a video file (you don't load the full video file into your app when you want to upload it, otherwise your app will probably crash as video files are extremely large). Does such a functionality exist? Or is there any other convenient way that I can't think of, that enables the app not to load the entire image file into its memory before posting it as a file?

Thanks, Can.